# Tikz: label of node, midway perpendicular to the node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to have to automatically give a position to a node label without needing to manually choose the angle using the label options. What I want is just to say "please go in the middle of this path, and perpendicularly to the path, mode n centimeters and place my label here". I don't want to specify manually the angle (too annoying to compute when you have not trivial paths), and the options `right` and `left` are not good because they don't go perpendicularly to the path, but rather horizontally or vertically.

Any idea?

Thanks.

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
A is too below, B is too right\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- node[midway,below]{A} node[midway,right]{B}
  node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=.5pt]{} (3,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try the `auto` key with possibly `swap`?

Comment: @percusse Indeed it seems to work pretty well, thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, someone asked more or less the same question quite recently: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431654

Answer (score 7):

Here are three different approaches.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- node[midway,below,sloped]{A}
    node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=.5pt]{} (3,1.5);

  \draw (0,-1) -- node[midway,below,sloped] (A) {\phantom{A}}
    node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=.5pt]{} (3,0.5);
  \node at (A) {A};

  \draw (0,-2) -- node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=.5pt] (B) {} (3,-0.5);
  \path ($(B)!\ht\strutbox!-90:(3,-0.5)$) node{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas! Just, do you know what is the differences between this and auto ? (I prefer your rendering, but I'm curious to know why)

Comment: and also, would it be possible to have some explanation on the last ($(B)!\ht\strutbox!-90:(3,-0.5)$), I'm not sure to get it

Comment: I wasn't that familiar with [auto], but I know [sloped] would work, and started playing with it.  Looking up [auto] in the manual, it is probably easier to use.  The calc solution is found on page 144.